# Swapping the carbs on my ducati m600

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, ducati

The mixer screws are totally seized on the carbs of my 1994 ducati m600, I have found a good set of carbs from a 1997 m600 but will they fit my bike?

Comment: You may wish to ask this on a Ducati forum. I'm sure you'll get a fast answer, the Monster has a huge following. If you do come across the answer elsewhere, please be sure to answer your own question here!

Answer (score 3):

## UPDATE

This Answer was valid until recently. BikeBandit.com stopped carrying Ducati.

Ducati Omaha does carry schematics online that allow the below answer to work, but they only have schematics 2000 and newer. However, their webpage says "For Prior Years - PLEASE CALL, we have access to the parts catalog back to 1993 for most models. 402-934-6627"

http://www.ducatiomaha.com/products.asp

Alex - This should give you what you need with your Ducati. For other motorcycle riders, the below information is still very useful.

---

## Original Answer

This question proactively allows users to answer this, and similar questions themselves.

"Will [part] from bike year XXXX fit on the same bike of a different year?"

BikeBandit.com has schematics for each motorcycle model and year. To see if a part from a 1994 M600 will fit on a 1997 M600:

1) Go to BikeBandit.com and select OEM Parts in the top-navigation.

2) Use the open the schematic for a 1994 M600.

2) Find the part you are looking for and notice the part number.

3) Open a new browser tab and go to BikeBandit.com, then open the schematic for the 1997 M600.

4) Find the part you are looking for.

5) If the part numbers are the same, the same part was used in both years.

When looking for replacement parts, it can be very useful to know all the bikes that use the same part.